# Error Setting up PerfectlySoft Swift on OS X

Tags: swift, perfect

When trying to build the most simple starter pack for PerfectlySoft Swift Server https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect, which simply involves the following steps per their website:

```
git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git
cd PerfectTemplate
swift build
.build/debug/PerfectTemplate
```

I get the following error multiple times during the step "Linking COpenSSL" which causes the build to error out "error: exit(1)":

```
@escaping attribute only applies to function types
```

I'm building this with Xcode command line tools V:8.0 (8S201h). What do I need to be doing differently to get this to work?

Comment: Are you using the right version of Swift? I see on their GitHub page: `The master branch of this project currently compiles with the August 26th Swift toolchain snapshot.`

Comment: Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.43.6 clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use DEVELOPMENT Snapshot instead a release version of Swift: 
[Swift Snapshot](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots)